# Cannot format pendrive, pendrive showing 100% disk usage in task manager?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I created my pendrive bootable for ubuntu using rufus yesterday, unfortunately it has started malfuctioning, now when I connect my pendrive to PC, file explorer freezes, I can't access menu to format it ?
In task manager it is showing 100% disk usage for pendrive!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot format pendrive,

Try formatting in a different computer. If that fails, the pendrive has failed and replacement is in order.

Comment: I bought it online and I can't replace it now! is there any other way ?

Comment: You may tgru Disk Management, right-click and remove the partition.

Comment: Disk management and diskpart both are freezed while scaning pendrive

Comment: So... That and *it has started malfuctioning* suggests it's defective. Again, *If that fails, the pendrive has failed and replacement is in order.* Nothing else to add.

Comment: Disk management and diskpart both are freezed while scaning pendrive   ----- so it is as I said, hardware error and the drive needs replacing.

Answer (score -1):

Try reformatting your pendrive using rufus again..
There is an option on rufus to format it to fat32...

or do the following:

Open Powershell (you can search this on statmenu)

In the PowerShell terminal, enter the following command:

format /FS:FAT32 DRIVE_LETTER:

example: format /FS:FAT32 D:

Comment: Very likely a waste of time.